# When is it safe to call pthread_attr_destroy?

Tags: linux, pthreads, detach

I am using pthreads on Linux. From the documentation, it is not clear to me when it is safe to call `pthread_attr_destroy` on the attributes I use to create a new thread? Can I do it immediately after `pthread_create` returns or do I have to wait until the thread is joined or detached?

Thanks in advance,
Christoph

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The thread attribute is copied in `pthread_create`, so it should be destroyed after `pthread_create` call.

Requires reading between lines here http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_create.html:

> If the attributes specified by attr are modified later, the thread's attributes shall not be affected.